# How to update the child table of inheriance type joined in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to update child table in inheritance type joined.

I tried

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update RuleAdhocActEntity as r set r.category=:category,r.ruleName=:ruleName,r.conditionName=:condition,r.fee=:fee,r.isFixedFee=:isFixedFee where r.rulesCode=:rulesCode")
public void updateAdhocRule(@Param(value = "rulesCode") String rulesCode,
        @Param(value = "category") String category, @Param(value = "ruleName") String ruleName,
        @Param(value = "condition") String conditon, @Param(value = "fee") Double fee,
        @Param(value = "isFixedFee") String isFixedFee);
```

where RuleAdhocActivity is a child of RuleEntity

thanks in advance

Comment: there was no error in the query but the values are not persisted in the database

Comment: Ca you show us the entities?

Comment: The answer to the question is: in a transaction load the entity, set the fields to the required values, commit the transaction. But since you posted some unrelated code, I guess you want to ask something different? Please clarify.